# script tag vs controller

Tags: angular, controller, script-tag

I have a block of code that runs fine in a script tag at the top of my HTML document, but once I move it inside of my angular controller, it stops working. Does anyone see what the problem with the code here might be? I'm getting the error that encodeImageFileAsURL is not defined

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function encodeImageFileAsURL() {
  let filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
  if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
    let fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    let srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

    let newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.src = srcData;

    document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
  }
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
 }
}
```

VS this:

```
$scope.encodeImageFileAsURL = function () {
let filesSelected = document.getElementById('inputFileToLoad').files;
if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
  let fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
  let fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent) {
    let srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
    let newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.src = srcData;

    document.getElementById('imgTest').innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
}
};
```

Comment: Can you defined ng-app in your html file?

Comment: The controller works fine just not this function. There are 250 other lines of JavaScript in the controller that are working

Comment: strange. can you create a plunker?

Comment: Please post all relevant code. For example, we can't see your entire controller so we don't know if you're properly injecting $scope.  Also, you haven't posted your html so we can't tell if you're calling $scope.encodeImageFileAsURL correctly.  That will help get you a better answer.  Also, are there any errors in your console?

Comment: if you paste this code into codepen.io it will run. Just copy and paste the style tag into and html document then add: 

     <input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" ng-model="fileToLoad" 
     onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" />
      <div id="imgTest"></div>

Comment: There is an error in the console that encodeImageFileAsURL is not defined

Comment: The controller has 250 lines of code, I can't paste them all here unfortunately

Comment: i see that if you write function in controller than you use "ng-change" replace of onchange like ng-change="encodeImageFileAsURL();"

Comment: ng-change doesn't produce a file preview, I have tried it

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/11541/

You can update you html like this

```
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" ng-model="fileToLoad" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().select(this)">
```

And your function like this

```
$scope.encodeImageFileAsURL = function(e){
    $scope.currentFile = e.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();


            reader.onload = function(event) {

              let srcData = event.target.result
                let newImage = document.createElement('img');
    newImage.src = srcData;

    document.getElementById('imgTest').innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;

            }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(e.files[0]);
                    //reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
  //console.log($scope.file)
  //var reader = new FileReader();

  }
```

Comment: awesome I will try to implement this

Comment: This produces a new error, but it seems to be on the right track.
Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).select is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (VM119648 media:1)

Comment: onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)" or try ng-change="encodeImageFileAsURL(this)"